# Parsear timestamp de texto con sistema persa Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Tengo problemas en parsear un timestamp en forma de cadena que está en persa/árabe

Al extraer el timestamp, lo que hay delante del `-` al parsear con un objeto data, da error

En persa/arabe
`٢٣‏/٨‏/٢٠١٧ ٢٣:٣٢ - ‏الرسائل والمكالمات مشفرة تمامًا، بحيث لا يستطيع أحد خارج هذه الدردشة، ولا حتى شركة واتساب نفسها، قراءتها أو الاستماع إليها. انقر هنا لمعرفة المزيد.`

traducido al ingles con google transalate
`8/23/2017 23:32 - Messages and calls are completely encrypted, so that no one outside of this chat, not even WhatsApp itself, can read or listen to it. Click here to learn more.`

Lo que he pensado, tras sacar el timestamp de la linea, convertir la númeración persa a sistema inglés 1..9, crear un objeto Date para guardar el timestamp.
Pero no ser si hay otra forma más directa

Comment: Piensa que está escrito de izquierda a derecha, el formato ahí es mm:hh yyyy/m/d

Answer (score 1):

Puedes seguir lo siguiente:

- Obtener la fecha con un `subtring`
- Partir la expresión en una serie de tokens
- Pasar cada token a un entero
- Crear un `LocalDateTime` (o cualquier herramienta para el manejo del tiempo)

```
val persian = Locale("fa", "af")
val numberFormat: NumberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(persian)

val text = """٢٣‏/٨‏/٢٠١٧ ٢٣:٣٢ - ‏الرسائل ولا يستطيع..."""

// "٢٣‏/٨‏/٢٠١٧ ٢٣:٣٢"
val textDate = text.substring(0..16)

val (day, month, year, hour, minute) = "[: /]".toRegex()
    .split(textDate, limit = 5)
    .map { numberFormat.parse(it).toInt() }
val date = LocalDateTime.of(year, month, day, hour, minute)
println(date) // "2017-08-23T23:32"
```

[image: Kotlin]